# Azure Authorization Failed for dnsZones

Tags: api, azure, dns, active-directory, authorization

I'm totally new with Microsoft Azure.

I'm trying to use their API for the DNS. After a long time I finally found how to create an application and how to obtain all needed keys. I also added the permission (I added all the permission for my tests for the moment) but I have the following error :

```
The client 'xxx' with object id 'xxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/read' over scope '/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/xxx'.
```

I thougth it was a permission issue but I added all the possible permission on the application. I don't unsertand much about Active Directory.

Can someone help me ? Thanks a lot.

EDIT:

What I did:

Create an application: Azure Active Directory > App Registration > Add > Create

Add permissions: Azure Active Directory > App Registration > View all applications > My app > Settings > Required Permissions > Windows Azure Active Directory > Check all Application Permissions and all Delegated Permissions > Save > Grant Persmission

Create Roles: Subscriptions > My subscription > Access Control (IAM) > Add > Select role 'DNS Zone Contributor' > Assign to my user.

Is there anything I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means you dont have permissions. :)

You need this permission: `Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/read`
over this scope: `/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/xxx`

you can grant these exact permissions with custom role, or use one of the built-in roles.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles

Comment: I used a built in role (this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#dns-zone-contributor) but I still have the error.

Comment: that means you didnt give permissions to the user\principal you are using. you gave it to the wrong user\wrong scope\etc

Comment: I edit my question to explain what I did. Is that right ?

Comment: you need to assign permissions not to your user, but to the application. you can use objectId provided in the error text

Comment: you can use powershell for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azurermps-6.6.0#create-a-service-principal-for-your-app you might try with the portal using the service princiapl name\objectid

Comment: Ok I found it. I assign the `DNS Zone Contributor` role to my application and it works